# Incrementing zRotation of SKSpriteNode causes compiler error on iphone5

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am having an issue understanding why the following code works fine on the iPhone5s simulator and but not on the iPhone5 and below simulator. wheel is a SKSpriteNode.

```
let spinSpeed = 0.7
wheel.zRotation += spinSpeed
```

The error is on the line which increments the zRotation. The error:

```
Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

I tried:

```
wheel.zRotation += Float(spinSpeed)
```

Which removes the error on the iPhone5 but now it is reporting the same error except now on the iPhone5s simulator instead.

I understand that the 5s uses a 64bit processor but I don't have much of a computer science background to understand the implication of this and how to fix this so it works on both phones.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by using CGFloat instead of Float

```
wheel.zRotation += CGFloat(spinSpeed)
```

Looks like the property zRotation is of type CGFloat. However I'm still confused as to why the original code worked fine on the 5s?